# C# trouble with including json.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, json.net

I have a webpart for SharePoint 2010 written on ASP.Net and I need to use JSON.Net. So I Nugeted Json.NET version 4.5.9. Then problem happens:

Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. Couldn't locate file.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the references menu and re-adding it?

Comment: Yes, i tried to delete and add again and it didn't help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same kind of problem once.

Don't use earlier references.

If you have any, remove them and add Json.Net once again using Nuget.

> **Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json**

It solved for me.

Comment: @Nana Delete references under references folder and also delete the packages using Mange *Nuget Packages option*

Comment: @Nana Try right-clicking the project and selecting "Manage NuGet packages" and then selecting the Json.Net

Comment: it's almost work, your answer help me. But this error appears then I write "JObject" in the code. Don't you know, what may it be?